# Fonts Flickering With CSS/jQuery Animation... What's Causing This?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, browser

This is the dev location for a site I am working on: http://www.plasticmonument.com/biomechaniks/index.html

Every time any jQuery slider animation takes place, all the fonts on the page flicker and or increase font-weight momentarily. What in the world is causing this? Driving me insane!

Comment: What browser (including version) are you using?  Don't see anything unusual in Chrome.

Comment: Please also include your OS - I don't see any issues on FF, Chrome or Safari in OSX 10.8.

Comment: I know Chrome does this.

Comment: Running OSX Lion
Happening on current version of Chrome (23.0.1271.101) and Safari. However, not happening on current version of Firefox. Haven't even checked it on IE yet. 

I could possibly take a screen recording of what I am seeing on my end.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One solution is to add this to CSS

```
html {-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased}
```

But I've just had a look around, apparently giving the animating element `position:relative` and the highest `z-index` on the page stops this from happening.

Comment: popnoodles - you sir, are a genius. Worked like a charm. Case closed.

Comment: @JustinMeyers, please click the checkmark next to this Answer to *Accept* it. Once accepted, it will turn green. Cheers!

Comment: For me, adding any `z-index` fixed this.